# HELP: I Broke Ubuntu By Uninstalling Compiz

Tags: unity, compiz, software-installation, gui

I'm still getting used to Linux, having come from Windows.  I was receiving an error that "compiz" had crashed a few times so I figured I'd uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove compiz
sudo apt-get install compiz
```

I logged out then back in, after that, the GUI was totally gone and I have no idea how to get it back or what I need to do to restore the GUI to what it was before I killed poor Compiz.  GUI was pretty much unmodified after a fresh install of 14.04

How can I fix it? I'm not even sure how to get to a terminal or anything.
The login screen looks normal, but after logging in, it's a totally bare desktop with my backround and a few icons.  No Dash, toolbar, etc.  Hot Keys don't seem to work either (Super = Dash doesn't work, etc); although I did accidently open "Disk" UI.  Not sure how.

Please Help!
Right now I'm working off my W7 dualboot.

Comment: Try opening a virtual terminal (CTRL + ALT + F1). Login and type `compiz`. Then press CTRL + ALT + F7 to return to the graphical interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the login screen , select for non-compiz session in the upper right corner (called "metacity" on my pc).
- If problem remains, try to install **gnome-session-flashback**, searching it in the software center or typing this command a terminal :
  sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback

  - To open a terminal with empty desktop, press alt+F2 then type
    gnome-terminal
  - If ALT+F2 don't work, press ctrl+alt+F1 and type login and password blindly: it will open a terminal.
    **gnome-session-flashback**  will give you one more choice in the login screen  for another  desktop type.
- You can also try reinstalling Compiz typing or copying this in a terminal:
  sudo apt-get --reinstall install compiz

Answer (score 3):

Compacted answer according to OP:

1. Switch to a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in with your user name and password.
2. Reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   This will restore all the missing packages necessary to run Ubuntu and the Unity desktop.
3. Either

   - reboot (`sudo reboot` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) or
   - restart the display manager¹ and switch back to the graphical interface (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

¹ to restart the display manager:

- on Trusty (14.04): `sudo initctl restart lightdm`
- on Wily (15.10) and later: `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`

---

Original answer by OP moved here from the question:

> Thanks @Laugeo and @ToDo, you both helped out.  Here's what I did...
>
> 1. Booted into Ubuntu with my broken desktop
> 2. Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open virtual terminal
> 3. `sudo install gnome-session-flashback`
> 4. Reboot
> 5. Launch session with Flashback (compiz)
> 6. Launch Terminal and type `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
> 7. Reboot
> 8. Back up and running
>
> Ultimately I suppose steps 3-5 weren't necessary, but they allowed me to get to a functional desktop and then I did more searching and found `ubuntu-desktop` to install.